# ./getXml.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: python, linux

I get the error:

> ./getXml.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   ./getXml.py: line 3:`tree=ET.parse("/home/svc_quickbuild/Documents/test/CI-TT-PSA.P4CNS.U-MAP.AFRICA.NDS-8.0.0.meta.xml")'

when i try to execute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree=ET.parse("/home/svc_quickbuild/Documents/test/CI-TT-PSA.P4CNS.U-MAP.AFRICA.NDS-8.0.0.meta.xml")

root= tree.getroot();

first_tag=root.find('tns:navigationSoftwareCompatibilityList').text

print(first_tag)
```

Comment: Share your input XML please.

Comment: This is an XML error, not a Python error. So you need to show us the XML.

Comment: Verify you XML at [xmlvalidation.com](https://xmlvalidation.com/)

Comment: I rectified it. It was the way i ran the python file that was wrong.